# Getting the received bytes of downloaded video in AVFoundation Framework for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

Hello I am using AVFoundation Framework to play clips from internet. I use `AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:URL`

Now I would like to check the size of received bytes from that video file. I couldn't find anything relevant on this page:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

So is there a way to find received byte size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent) Class.

You can access via `

```
self.aPlayer.currentItem.accessLog
AVPlayerItemAccessLog *accesslog = self.aPlayer.currentItem.accessLog;  
NSArray *events = [accesslog events];    
AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent *event = [events objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSLog(@"Number of bytes received %@", [event numberOfBytesTransferred]);
```

You have Accesslog which gives you details about 
Data Properties

```
  numberOfSegmentsDownloaded  property
  numberOfMediaRequests  property
  playbackStartDate  property
  URI  property
  serverAddress  property
  numberOfServerAddressChanges  property
  playbackSessionID  property
  playbackStartOffset  property
  segmentsDownloadedDuration  property
  durationWatched  property
  numberOfStalls  property
  numberOfBytesTransferred  property
  indicatedBitrate  property
  observedBitrate  property
  numberOfDroppedVideoFrames  property
```

IMO, This is the only option you have, but this has its flaws too, especially when seeking etc.

Comment: What is the purpose of [events objectAtIndex:0] ?

I am having a problem with that if I skip some parts on the video, e.g jumping from 5th second to 10th. In that case numberOfBytesTransferred value does not change.

Comment: Well it takes into account number of events. events is a NSArray and thats why the objectAtIndex:0. You could very well loop through all the events. I have not tried myself, but maybe after seek, a new event gets updated! Will try myself and update answer when I get time.

Comment: How often does this accessLog being updated? Does it have accessLog event listener?